# How to enable GPU while deploying a Pytorch model using Vertex custom prediction routine

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am really new to model deployment and using Vertex AI tools so my problem probably come from something really stupid I may have done but I have difficulties to find documentation about this.

I want to deploy a segmentation model and chose to use Vertex AI Custom Prediction Routines since I need to add preprocessing, postprocessing and browse for additionnal data.
I used [this sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/vertex-ai-samples/blob/main/notebooks/community/prediction/custom_prediction_routines/SDK_Pytorch_Custom_Predict.ipynb) to get the idea of the steps I needed to follow but had issues to upload the model (with `aiplatform.Model.upload`) after pushing the image si I did this step manually with the console (the image were already pushed to artifacts registries).
Right now, the models acts as expected (preprocesses, predicts and postprocess smoothly) but it doesn't seem to be able to use gpu, even if I deploy it to an endpoint using gpu (I tried the 3 aviable accelerators and 2 different machines ( n1-standard-2 and n1-highmem-2).
`torch.cuda_is_aviable` returns `False` and trying `torch.zeros(1).cuda()` returns `Found no NVIDIA driver on your system. Please check that you have an NVIDIA GPU and installed a driver from http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx`

I tried to change the pytorch libraries to use, right now I am using torchvision 0.14.1+cu116 and torch 1.13.1+cu116

I don't know which piece of code could be relevant since the whole process works when using cpu and the issue appears at the very beginning. Would you have an idea of the possible source of this issue ? The problem seems to come from the fact that there are no gpu drivers but Google provided functions should take care of this since I use custom prediction routines, am I mistaken ?

I also wonder if the problem could be caused by the fact that my machine doesn't have gpu itself ?